# dependent select box doesn't load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i've some codes that should fetch data from database and display it as select boxes
dependent on the first choice.

In the index.php i have a jquery code .change(function(){..}) which should fill the second select box when the first one changes, and i think the problem is here because i checked the developer tools in chrome, the action.php should be loaded in the network tab if the action load_month is sent by ajax and it never happens.

Could somebody help to figure out what is the problem ?

function.php

```
function fill_product_list($connect)
{
    $query = 
    SELECT * FROM product 
    WHERE product_status = 'active' 
    ORDER BY product_name ASC
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $output = '';
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["product_id"].'">'.$row["product_name"].'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}

function fill_month_list_product_wise($connect, $poduct_id)
{
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM month
    INNER JOIN stock ON stock.month_id = month.month_id
    WHERE stock.product_id = '".$product_id."'
    ORDER BY monat_id ASC
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $output = '<option value="">date of delivery </option>';
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["month_id"].'">'.$row["month_name"].'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

index.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>products</label>
    <hr />
    <span id="span_product_details"></span>
    <hr />
</div>

<script>
function add_product_row(count = '')
        {
            var html = '';
            html += '<span id="row'+count+'"><div class="row">';
            html += '<div class="col-md-8">';
            html += '<select name="product_id[]" id="product_id" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>';
            html += '<?php echo fill_product_list($connect); ?>';
            html += '</select><input type="hidden" name="hidden_product_id[]" id="hidden_product_id'+count+'" />';
            html += '<select name="month_id[]" id="month_id'+count+'" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>';
            html += '</select><input type="hidden" name="hidden_month_id[]" id="hidden_month_id'+count+'" />';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div class="col-md-3">';
            html += '<input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" required />';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div class="col-md-1">';
            if(count == '')
            {
                html += '<button type="button" name="add_more" id="add_more" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">+</button>';
            }
            else
            {
                html += '<button type="button" name="remove" id="'+count+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove">-</button>';
            }
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div></div><br /></span>';
            $('#span_product_details').append(html);

            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        }

        var count = 0;

        $(document).on('click', '#add_more', function(){
            count = count + 1;
            add_product_row(count);
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
            var row_no = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#row'+row_no).remove();
        });

// Here is the Problem, the action load_month never execute 
    $('#product_id').change(function(){
        var product_id = $('#product_id').val();
        var btn_action = 'load_month';
        $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{product_id:product_id, btn_action:btn_action},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#month_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

action.php

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_action']))
{
    if($_POST['btn_action'] == 'load_month')
    {
        echo fill_month_list_product_wise($connect, $_POST['product_id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: when this function add_product_row will be called? I am not seeing any id loaded to call it.

Comment: @PHPHuppTechnologies
here after var count =0;

$(document).on('click', '#add_more', function(){
            count = count + 1;
            add_product_row(count);
        });

Comment: Hints: 1) IDs must be unique within a html document (by definition, that's the whole point of an ID). You can't select more than one element with the same ID, but your add row function keeps creating more drop-downs with the same ID. Use a class to identify the drop-downs instead. 2) you need to learn about event delegation, so you can write code which handles events on elements which don't yet exist in the page when the event handler is declared.